# L'emprunt « ultracrépidarianisme » est-il adéquatement préfixé/suffixé et pourquoi doit-il être adapté ou non ?

Tags: anglais, préfixes, suffixes, emprunts

Je lis pour la première fois le mot *ultracrépidarianisme* ([article](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/chroniques/2022-01-08/l-epidemie-d-ultracrepidarianisme.php), [origine](https://dictionnaire.orthodidacte.com/article/definition-ultracrepidarianisme), [Wiki](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultracr%C3%A9pidarianisme)), soit le substantif référant au « comportement consistant à donner son avis sur des sujets à propos desquels on n’a pas de compétence crédible ou démontrée » (Wikipédia). C'est un emprunt à l'anglais qui lui est formé sur un adjectif<sup>1</sup> (*ultracrepidarian*), le tout étant peut-être inspiré d'une [maxime latine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutor,_ne_supra_crepidam), *sutor, ne supra [crepida](https://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=crepida)m* ; c'est d'un emploi assez récent en français (Orthodidacte).

Ma première impression, personnelle, est que préfixe [*ultra-*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ultra-) m'a fait penser au haut degré et j'ai trouvé que la « syllabe de l'adjectif » était suprenante et rendait le mot long.

---

1. Le mot est-il adéquatement préfixé, la maxime contient *supra*,
   est-ce *utlra* ou *extra*, est-ce *hors/outre* ou *à l'extérieur de*
   ou autrement, que considère-t-on le plus cohérent ?
2. Le mot est-il adéquatement suffixé, *crepida, ae* est un nom,
   peut-on justifier l'utilité de la finale adjectivale (-rian) en
   français ; la finale en -isme convient-elle ?
3. L'emprunt est-il spontanément compréhensible, pourquoi devrait-il
   être adapté ou non en français ; est-il courant d'adapter le préfixe/suffixe d'un emprunt à la langue anglaise ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> En ce sens que l'emploi [original](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutor,_ne_ultra_crepidam) était en adjectif (« *You have been well called an Ultra-Crepidarian critic* ») mais le [nom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ultracrepidarian#Noun) existe aussi.</sub>

Comment: Le mot a été inventé par l'anglais en question. Alors, on l'emprunte ou on ne l'emprunte pas. Critiquer un mot inventé de cette façon me semble bizarre. Weekend, adapté au français ou pas?

Comment: @Lambie Non, on critique les emprunts et leur adéquation avec la norme linguistique, sa morphologie, sa syntaxe et sa sémantique, ce n'est pas tout ou rien. On reste curieux, et pas soumis à la norme linguistique d'une langue étrangère. [_Weekend_](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8361442) est un emprunt intégral qui n'est ni préfixé ni suffixé. Je ne vois pas la rapport.

Comment: @Lambie Le latin a _supra_ comme j'ai indiqué. Le sens peut aussi être conçu comme à l'extérieur de son expertise, et _ultra_ est aussi associé à l'exagération. Donc non et non.

Comment: "Le sens peut aussi être conçu comme à l'extérieur de son expertise, et ultra est aussi associé à l'exagération".= Exactement. Voilà le sens ici. Tout cela marche. Les trois explications que **vous avez donné**.

Comment: Mais il ne s'agit pas de répéter l'anglais. Le tout est venu du Latin de toute façon. Répéter l'anglais serait de dire des mots comme leadership, par exemple. Il n'y absolumment rien dans le mot "ultracrépidarianisme" qui soit "anglais* en soi.

Comment: @Lambie -rian-.

Comment: Ok, j'ai essayé de donner mon opinion. Soyez rassurez que je suis ultra francophile et je serait la première à critiquer toute entorse anglicisante aux articulations du génie de la langue française dans les limites de mes capacités linguistiques, bien sûr.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, merci, mais tu aurais pu simplement répondre : le préfixe convient, les autres ne seraient pas meilleurs ; les finales sont claires, _rian_ n'est pas superflu ; le mot est compréhensible, ne devrait pas être adapté vu X ; on aurait à changer le mot s'il était vraiment incompatible. Je ne sais pas, j'extrapole de ton propos. J'interprète tes multitples commentaires et la comparaison avec weekend et l'affirmation que le mot en question ne contient aucun élément d'anglais malgré _rian_ comme une manière de _sidetracker_ la question. J'aurais interprété une réponse différemment.

Comment: *ultra-* et *-isme* ne me choquent pas mais le suffixe aurait pu être raccourci oui, sur le modele
vegetarianism - végétarisme /
rastafarianism - rastafarisme /
...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Le mot est-il adéquatement préfixé, la maxime contient supra, est-ce utlra ou extra, est-ce hors/outre ou à l'extérieur de ou autrement, que considère-t-on le plus cohérent ?

=> Le mot n'est aucunement "préfixé" : le "ultra" en question n'est pas un préfixe ajouté par l'utilisateur du néologisme, mais l'élément central de la maxime.

Ta maxime a des formes alternatives. Anciennement, la plus connue et citée était "Ne sutor ULTRA crepidam" : que le cordonnier ne juge pas AU-DESSUS de la sandale. Physiquement au-dessus, plus haut que la cheville. C'est à cet "ultra" que fait référence l'ultra-crépidarianisme, qui donc n'est pas un "sur-crépidarianisme", ou un "crépidarianisme amélioré". Ça fait partie intégrante du concept, qui se définit précisément par le fait de juger AU-DELÀ de la SANDALE.

Proposer l'ablation d'ultra dans ultracrépidarianisme pour faire plus court reviendrait à proposer de raccourcir les "départements ultramarins" en "départements marins", ou "l'ultramontanisme" en "montanisme". Il ne s'agit pas de préfixes de renforcement, mais d'un élément fondamental de l'adjectif substantivé (ou vice-versa) : les ultramarins sont des outres-mers (donc, pas les mers qui bordent la métropole), et les ultramontains sont ceux pour le pouvoir papal au-delà des montagnes (donc, de l'autre côté des Alpes, en Italie).

Comment: Dans une chanson « Faire prout prout plus haut que son lonlère » https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/peter-plus-haut-que-son-cul

Comment: Éventuellement, si tu as un complément sur l'utilité de _-rian_, n'hésite pas à l'ajouter.